# I want to insert attachment in particular list item using pnpjs

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, attachments, react

I want to update the list item with attachment but not sure why its failing the payload while saving it.

```
try {
 sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.select(item.Title).add((r => {
 // this will add an attachment to the item we just created to push t sharepoint list
 r.item.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.UploadedFilesArray.name, this.state.UploadedFilesArray).then(result=>{
console.log(result);
    });
 }));
} catch(e){
console.log(e);
 }
```

Comment: You can check this answer, it might help you :https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/240439/87201

Comment: @HabiburRahaman Tried that but not working, I want to add in a item. And that approach  create a new item.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this code:

```
...items.select(item.Title)...
```

Correct way:

```
...items.select("Title")...
```

You don't even need `.select("Title")` part. You are creating list item. thereis no point in selecting columns here. keep it simple like so:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items...
```

I don't think this syntax is correct. It's unclear what you are doing here:

```
.add((r => {..)
```

items.add method adds list item. this is the right syntax:

```
.items.add({Title: 'New List item'})
```

Then, to add an attachment you can do it like so:

```
  let newListItem = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items.add({Title: 'new Item'});
  await newListItem.item.attachmentFiles.add("file.txt","Some content");
```

Or, if you can't use async/awayt, do it like so:

```
  sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items.add({ Title: 'new Item 2' }).then(newListItem => {
    newListItem.item.attachmentFiles.add("file.txt", "Some content");
  })
```

**Update**

If you want to select an existing list item by id:

```
let item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items.getById(1);
item.attachmentFiles.add("file.txt", "Some content");
```

If you need to get list items by Title and add attachments to these items:

```
let item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items.filter("Title eq 5").getAll().then(items => {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

      let currentItem = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("CustomList").items.getById(items[i].Id);
      currentItem.attachmentFiles.add("file 2.txt", "Some content 2");
    }
  })
```

I was using [SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en) Chrome extension for debugging this script:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add attachment to a list item through below PowerShell.

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$ListName = "Projects"
$ItemID ="2"
$FilePath ="C:\Docs\UserInfo.csv"
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
#Get the List Item
$Item  = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Id $ItemID
#Get the File and Add to List Item Attachment
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($FilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$AttachmentInfo = New-Object -TypeName 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCreationInformation
$AttachmentInfo.FileName =  Split-Path $FilePath -Leaf
$AttachmentInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$AttchedFile = $Item.AttachmentFiles.Add($AttachmentInfo)
Invoke-PnPQuery
$FileStream.Close()
```

Reference:[Add Attachment to List Item using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-add-attachment-to-list-item-using-powershell.html)